# Setting padding on Zurb Foundation's Button mixin

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, mixins

I'm trying to use Foundation's [Button Mixin](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/buttons.html). The format example from the docs is this:

```
// Using the available options
.custom-button-class {
  @include button($padding, $bg, $radius, $full-width, $disabled, $is-input);
}
```

So I'm using it like so:

```
@include button(rem-calc(10 5), $colour-main-orange, em-calc(5 0), false, false, false);
```

But passing `rem-calc(10 5)` as the padding is failing. Compass fails to compile the SCSS with error: `Undefined operation: "0.625rem 0.3125rem times 2"`

If I pass just `rem-calc(10)` it works. In most other areas around Foundation, multiple values can be passed in this way. For example see the way I'm passing radius values of top-left and bottom-right = 5 and top-right and bottom-left = 0.

Can anyone think of a way around this? It might be a mixin bug, but before I try and work out how to fix it I want to make sure it's not just me being stupid!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Parhum says you can't use a list as a `$padding` argument for this mixin so I have modified one of my mixins to add lists support to button mixin. Button mixin imports button-size mixin to deal with button padding so you need to edit button-size mixin to add support to use lists as arguments for `$padding`.

Here is my [mixin](https://gist.github.com/guerrero/7777219)

**How it works**
With this mixin you can set `$padding` as a value, a list with a single value or a list with 2, 3 or 4 values, this list follows the css rule for padding shorthand:

> - **One** single value applies to all 4 sides
> - **Two** values apply to **1.** top and bottom and **2.** to the left and right side
> - **Three** values apply to **1.** top, **2.** right and left and **3.** to the bottom side
> - **Four** values apply to **1.** top, **2.** right, **3.** bottom and **4.** to the left side

So `@include button-size($padding: value)` returns:

```
padding-top: value
padding-right: value * 2
padding-bottom: value + rem-calc(1)
padding-left: value * 2
```

`@include button-size($padding: value1 value2)` returns:

```
padding-top: value1
padding-right: value2 * 2
padding-bottom: value1 + rem-calc(1)
padding-left: value2 * 2
```

`@include button-size($padding: value1 value2 value3)` returns:

```
padding-top: value1
padding-right: value2 * 2
padding-bottom: value3 + rem-calc(1)
padding-left: value2 * 2
```

`@include button-size($padding: value1 value2 value3)` returns:

```
padding-top: value1
padding-rigth: value2 * 2
padding-bottom: value3 + rem-calc(1)
padding-left: value4 * 2
```

**Proportion**
I've added another argument to box-size mixin called `$proportion`, it's set to true by default and if you set it to a true value it removes padding operations.

So `@include button-size($padding: value1 value2 value3 value4, $proportion: )` returns:

```
padding-top: value1
padding-rigth: value2
padding-bottom: value3
padding-left: value4
```

instead of:

```
padding-top: value1
padding-right: value2 * 2
padding-bottom: value3 + rem-calc(1)
padding-left: value4 * 2
```

**How to include this mixin in foundation**

1. Open fundation/components/_buttons.scss with your favourite editor and replace `@mixin button-size` by this [mixin](https://gist.github.com/guerrero/7777219)
2. Add `$proportion:false` into `@mixin button` arguments and into `@include button-size` arguments

Comment: At first thank you for editing my answer :)
But about your solution, I think better don't edit Core files(Core files here is Foundation Components) and better add your value for `padding-bottom` after `@include button;`. like this: `@include button; padding-bottom: rem-calc(10px);`

Because in future, Foundation release new update and you have to edit big mixin!

Comment: This is excellent! Please please add it to the core: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_buttons.scss - I'm sure it'll be accepted.

Comment: I found this post yesterday, but the Gist was down, and when I asked a repeat question it got shut down and pointed here for the answer.  Could you repost the Gist?

Comment: @mtpultz gist updated, is an old snippet so the code should be improved

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to set $padding argument as a list with two values, @mixin button takes this list and tries to operate with it but returns an error because sass doesn't support list operations . From Sass Reference:

> Lists don’t support any special operations. Instead, they’re
>   manipulated using the list functions.

Foundation use this code to set $padding that you send to them. Look at this code:

```
padding-top: $padding;
padding-#{$opposite-direction}: $padding * 2; // $padding list and * operator returns an error
padding-bottom: $padding + rem-calc(1); // This also return an error
padding-#{$default-float}: $padding * 2; // This also return an error
```